# Riddle: I'm like Death and Childbirth

Tags: riddle

> I'm short
> and I don't snore.
>
> I'm demanding
> and can't be ignored.
>
> When my time comes it will be inconvenience,
> living up to the reputation of non-lenience.
>
> Though I am not your wife nor your girlfriend,
> your saving is emptied the same way at the end.
>
> Are you thinking about love,
> are you thinking about life?
>
> Get back to work and throw your imagination aside!

I am...?

Comment: This is *probably* nitpicking, but shouldn't the last line say throw your imagination aside?

Comment: @n_palum your suggestion sounds better, i'll edit it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you..

> Taxes

I'm short

> It's a short word?

and I don't snore.

> Taxes seem to be never ending

I'm demanding

> taxes demand effort to be filed and also demand for money

and can't be ignored.

> you can't ignore your taxes!!

When my time comes it will be inconvenience,

> Taxes are always inconvenient

living up to the reputation of non-lenience.

> Tax credit

Though I am not your wife nor your girlfriend,
your saving is emptied the same way at the end.

> taxes take up money

Are you thinking about love,
are you thinking about life?

Get back to work and throw your imagination aside!

> taxes are work and requires very little imagination unless you are faking them

Comment: You got it, nicely done!

Answer (score 1):

Nearly certain I'm wrong, but I'll take a stab. Are you:

> Pain?

I'm short

> Pain is a 4-letter word

and I don't snore.

> I'm not sure

I'm demanding
and can't be ignored.

> Pain is a feeling sent by your nerves directly to the brain, and is basically a red flag.

When my time comes it will be inconvenience,

> When you are in crippling pain, it can be difficult to walk, breathe, etc (very inconvenient).

living up to the reputation of non-lenience.

> Pain is often unrelenting unless measures are taken to fix the root of the issue.

Though I am not your wife nor your girlfriend,
your saving is emptied the same way at the end.

> I'm not sure

Are you thinking about love,
are you thinking about life?

Get back to work and throw your imaginary aside!

> I don't really know about these as well. Pain does have the same number of letters as both love and life. Maybe the last line has something to do with fighting through the pain and that it's all in your head?

Title significance:

> While people often die peacefully, death is frequently accompanied by pain. Babies come into the world crying (maybe they feel pain, I'm not sure), and childbirth is supposed to be one of the most painful events a person can endure.

Comment: Not the correct answer but one of the line is actually correct.

Answer (score 1):

You are

> A baby

I'm short

> babies are much smaller than an adult

and I don't snore.

> many babies never seem to sleep

I'm demanding
and can't be ignored.

> the baby's cry is designed to be un-ignorable so the child will be attended to by his parents.

When my time comes it will be inconvenience,
living up to the reputation of non-lenience.

> having a baby is very inconvenient, and there's often no way out of it

Though I am not your wife nor your girlfriend,
your saving is emptied the same way at the end.

> raising a child costs a LOT of money

Are you thinking about love,
are you thinking about life?

Get back to work and throw your imagination aside!

> once you have a baby, you don't get to spend as much time on your romantic relationship, your career, or your dreams and hobbies. Your main focus needs to be on work to provide for the baby.

Comment: Yes, I saw it, but I thought I could still share my answer since it is not a duplicate and I personally think it is a fantastic answer to the riddle posed.